# Issue with Gradle exclude transitive dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I am having Gradle 3.0. With gradle I am trying to load JasperReports 6.3.0. Here is dependency configuration for the same.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.9.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.9.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE"

    //
    // JasperReports
    //
    compile group: 'org.olap4j', name: 'olap4j', version: '1.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.castor', name: 'castor-xml', version: '1.4.1'
    compile ('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.castor'
    }
}
```

Issue I was facing is because of JasperReports 6.3.0's transitive dependency with Castor XML 1.3.3, it was loading Spring Framework 3.0.6 version, which was quite old. Instead I wanted to load Spring Framework 3.2.9. To avoid castor 1.3.3 I've excluded from dependency list. But it still loads Castor 1.3.3 and so Spring Framework 3.0.6. Here is some snippet from Gradle dependency report.

```
11:34:55.175 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/codehaus/castor/castor-xml/1.3.3/castor-xml-1.3.3.pom
11:34:56.175 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/codehaus/castor/castor/1.3.3/castor-1.3.3.pom
11:34:57.429 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/codehaus/castor/castor-core/1.3.3/castor-core-1.3.3.pom
11:34:58.545 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:34:59.626 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:35:00.659 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-aop/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:35:01.697 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:35:02.687 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:35:03.723 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:35:04.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:35:04.526 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:35:04.526 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:35:04.527 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:35:04.780 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-expression/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
11:35:06.729 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-test/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-test-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
11:35:07.703 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-parent/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
11:35:11.694 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/codehaus/castor/castor-xml/1.3.3/castor-xml-1.3.3.jar
11:35:11.700 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/webflow/spring-binding/2.0.8.RELEASE/spring-binding-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
11:35:11.710 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-orm/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
11:35:11.711 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/webflow/spring-webflow/2.0.8.RELEASE/spring-webflow-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
11:35:11.717 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/webflow/spring-js/2.0.8.RELEASE/spring-js-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
11:35:12.585 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/codehaus/castor/castor-core/1.3.3/castor-core-1.3.3.jar
11:35:12.790 [QUIET] [system.out] |Downloading: org/springframework/spring-test/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-test-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
11:35:14.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:35:14.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:35:14.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:35:14.532 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: The [following](https://gist.github.com/Opalo/063357d666acc94e6754a9c2ce90bf4b) piece of code downloads required dependencies only. Have you tried cleaning the cache?

Comment: Yes, I have deleted gradle cache and project cache. It still goes to download castor 1.3.3 and so Spring framework 3.0.6

Comment: I've exactly the same version and it works.